# VBA Userform ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to populate a ComboBox on a UserForm when it initializes from a Named range. Have not had any luck. Any help is appreciated.

```
 Private Sub MVPForm_Initialize()

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Broker ID Lookup")

 'Add latest brokers
 Me.BrokerName.List = ws.Range("MVP_Brokers").Value

 End Sub
```

Comment: It's **always** `Userform_Initialize` regardless of the name of the form.

Comment: @Rory haha wow I feel dumb. easy fix. thanks

Comment: Don't worry - you're not the first person to do it, and you won't be the last! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never type event handler signatures by hand. If the method name isn't *exactly* as VBA expects it, then the callback won't be invoked. If the callback has parameters and your method doesn't have them all *in the same order*, very hard-to-debug problems can happen.

Instead, let the VBE create these method stubs for you, by picking an interface from the left-hand dropdown at the top of the code pane, then picking a method to implement in the right-hand dropdown:

[image: pick 'UserForm' from the left dropdown]

[image: pick 'Initialize' from the right dropdown]

The correct signature will be generated automatically every time:

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

End Sub
```

Watch the left dropdown: whenever you're inside what you expect to be an event handler and it says "(General)", you're actually looking at dead/unreachable code.